# Why does my javascript file not work when it is accessed by more than one html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to submit a form on one page, put it in an array in a javascript file, and then have the information I submitted appear on another page. I can only make it work if I put in the information on the same page though. Otherwise it doesn't work. Here is my code for begin.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <form>
        <label for="planet">Select a Planet:</label>
        <select id="planet" name="planet">
            <option value="mercury">Mercury</option>
            <option value="venus">Venus</option>
            <option value="earth">Earth</option>
            <option value="mars">Mars</option>
            <option value="jupiter">Jupiter</option>
            <option value="saturn">Saturn</option>
            <option value="uranus">Uranus</option>
            <option value="neptune">Neptune</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <label for="departureDate">Departure Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="departureDate" name="departureDate"><br><br>

        <label for="planet2">Select a Planet:</label>
        <select id="planet2" name="planet">
            <option value="mercury">Mercury</option>
            <option value="venus">Venus</option>
            <option value="earth">Earth</option>
            <option value="mars">Mars</option>
            <option value="jupiter">Jupiter</option>
            <option value="saturn">Saturn</option>
            <option value="uranus">Uranus</option>
            <option value="neptune">Neptune</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <label for="departureDate2">Departure Date:</label>
        <input type="date2" id="departureDate2" name="departureDate2"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./plans.js"></script>
    
    <button onclick="location.href = 'planetwindow.html';" id="thing" class="float-left submit-button">Search Flights</button>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then here is my code for planet window.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>You are on Saturn idk</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>You did it</div>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <button type = "submit" onclick="location.href = 'game.html'"; id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button">Go to next thing</button>
    <script src = "plans.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

And finally here is the code for my javascript file. The part document.getElementById("test").innerHTML works if I try to put it on something with the ID of test in the begin.html file. However, it stops working as soon as I try to use it for an element in the planetwindow.html file.

```
    {
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    var arr = [];
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent HTML refresh
        const fd = new FormData(form); // Converts to array of arrays
        for (item of fd) {
        arr.push(item);
        }
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = arr[0][1];
    });

}
```

Comment: 1. Remove `type=submit` from the button than does a location change
2. The script you showed looks incomplete. What is expected behaviour? That what you fill on begin shows on planet? How would that happen? The script that fills formdata does not survive the load of the next page. You need sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

I think the following idea should do what you're looking for
You can store the form data in localStorage in begin.html and retrieve it in planetwindow.html.